# how to catch angular ng-include error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

When I use `ng-include` as a title, how do I catch the error when the address (file path) does not exist?

I finished a `ng-include router` inside a `ng-view(with ng-route)`,
It's a little bit like this:

**ContentCtrl**:

```
var content = $route.current.params.content,
    tmplArr = content.split("_"),
    tmpl = {},
    personId=$route.current.params.personId||$scope.persons[0].id;
$scope.personId=personId;
tmpl.url = "content/";
for (var i = 0, len = tmplArr.length; i < len; i++) {
    tmpl.url += tmplArr[i] + "/";
}
tmpl.url = tmpl.url.substring(0, tmpl.url.length - 1) + ".html";
$scope.template = tmpl;
```

**ContentView**:

```
<div ng-include="template.url" class="ng-animate"></div>
```

when I use the addr is not exist like:/home/#/content/profile_asdfa,
the angular just fetch the resource  in a loop.
So I need to catch the ng-include error,when there is no template file in the hash.
Can anybody Help me ? Thx!

Comment: Not related to your question, but it might be better to not include the `ng-animate` class in the element. This is added (+ removed) automatically when Angular does its enter/leave animations, so it might cause slightly unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking in the [source for ngInclude](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.5/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L3), there seems to be no hook or way to detect directly a 404 (or  other) error when the template doesn't exist. You might want to consider a feature request to add this, as it sounds like a useful feature.

However, right now you could do something with a http response interceptor. If there is some way to tell if a http reguest is for a template, say it is in the 'content' directory, you can intercept errors, and do something with them. For example you could replace the data with a custom directive, that then emits an event so controller(s) could respond to it.

The interceptor could be written like:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('templateInterceptor');
});

// register the interceptor as a service
app.factory('templateInterceptor', function($q) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
       var isTemplate = !!rejection.config.url.match(/^content/g);
       if (isTemplate) {
         rejection.data = '<div><template-error url="\''+ (rejection.config.url) + '\'"><strong>Error from interceptor.</strong></template-error></div>';
         return rejection;
       } else {
         return $q.reject(rejection);
       }
    }
  }
});
```

So when there is an error after fetching something from the 'content' directive, it adds an element `<template-error>` in place of the template content. When this is compiled and then linked, it `$emit`s a custom event, `templateError`, which parent controllers can respond to, by `$scope.$on`. So the directive can be code up like:

```
app.directive('templateError', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'url': '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$emit('templateError', {url:scope.url});
    }
  };
});
```

And then in the parent controller of the original `ngInclude`, you can react to this event:

```
$scope.$on('templateError', function(e, data) {
  $scope.templateError = true;
  $scope.templateErrorUrl = data.url;
})
```

You can see the [full working code in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8eSgJau2EzVBbf9M4Ke?p=preview). Although I think this is slightly hacky, if the Angular team decide to add an `$emit`ed event to the code of `ngInclude` on error, then it should be easy to just remove the interceptor / your custom element.

Comment: It seems your scheme can solve my problem, I will try it out later. Thx a lot : )

Comment: Can I assume the same solution will work when loading a ng-view template?

Comment: @ruben I don't see why not... You can always try it and see :-)