# Confused about $http interceptors in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http-interceptors

Really can not find good documentation about http interceptors in Angular js. While handling errors coused by `ng-include` i can intercept `responseError` by using this:

```
    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('templateInterceptor');
});

// register the interceptor as a service
app.factory('templateInterceptor', function($q) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
       var isTemplate = !!rejection.config.url.match(/^content/g);
       if (isTemplate) {
         // here we add error message, but how this message appesrs in the place of ng-include
         rejection.data = '<div><template-error url="\''+ (rejection.config.url) + '\'"><strong>Error from interceptor.</strong></template-error></div>';
         return rejection;
       } else {
         return $q.reject(rejection);
       }
    }
  }
});
```

This code was taken from this question [how to catch angular ng-include error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836374/how-to-catch-angular-ng-include-error) .
I don't get, how interceptors works? What they must return? How to use `rejection` parameter that passed to the `responseError` interceptor? In `rejection` the `data` property is used to include error message into the place of failed `ng-include` directive,  how this works?

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have call to `$http`, such as

```
$http(....).then(function(results) {
  // Success callback
}, function(error) {
  // Error callback
});
```

And the server responds with an error, then the responseError interceptors will get invoked before running either the success or error callbacks.

- If the final interceptor returns any value that is not a promise, then from the point of view of the calling code, the call to `$http` was successful, and the success callback will be executed, passing in the returned value as the `results` argument
- If the final interceptor returns a promise that gets resolved with a value, then similar to the case above, from the point of view of the calling code, the call to `$http` was successful, and the success callback will be executed, passing in the resolved value as the `results` argument.
- If the final interceptor returns a promise that is rejected with an error, then from the point of view of the calling code, the call to `$http` was *not* successful, and the error callback will be executed, passing in the rejected error as the `error` argument.

The `ngInclude` directive will inject into the page the `data` key from the results of a successful call to `$http`. The code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838764/1319998 transforms what would be an errored call to `$http` from `ngInclude`, into a success, with html of an error message as the `data` key in the result.